# How to pass any data to the newly created web service

Tags: wcf, testing, inversion-of-control

I am working at the client-server application which server part will have more than one logical processors to process client requests. Moreover is assumed that communication channels shouldn't be only TCP/IP, for example, but at least RS485-based as well.

The simplified sheme is shown on the picture below:
[image: The simplified sheme of the server-client communication, described above]
So, the question: how can I pass the IRequestProcessor reference to the IConnection WCF implementation instance, which is created automatically by the WCF framework as the response to an incoming request?

According to the picture: how can be realized the links, shown with the bold arrows, for the WCF IConnection instances?

First thought was to implement some static memeber for the WcfConnection (which is IConnection implementation) class. This static member should hold the selector which will select the appropriate IRequestProcessor implementation instance using some rules. But I hope there whould be better solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is WCF extension - custom IInstanceProvider implementation:

1. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/31/wcf-extensibility-iinstanceprovider.aspx
2. http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/introducing-unity.wcf-providing-easy-ioc-integration-for-your-wcf-services